# Center of Mass calculation in configuration of $3$ pennies inscribing equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

I'm working on a problem that is asking me to solve the moment of inertia about the center of mass of a $3$ penny system where the edge of each penny is touching the edge of the others and the configuration forms an equilateral triangle shape. The pennies each have mass $M$ and radius $R$.

Now, I know this is a parallel-axis theorem problem and that the result is of the form $$I = 3(I_{CM} + Mr^2)$$ Where $r$ is the distance from the parallel axis to the Center of Mass axis of each of the pennies. On my attempt I simply took $r = R$ since the I figured that the center of mass (of the $3$ penny system) was in the middle of the small space in between each penny (since they are of equal mass) and that leaves a little more than a distance of $R$ (however I just took $R$ as I wasn't sure how to calculate that little extra distance).

Upon looking at the solution the correct $r$ is actually $r = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}R \approx 1.155R$. My intuition was correct, however after reading the explanation I'm still not seeing how we arrived at this value for $r$. The explanation given is as follows: "It's a useful fact that the center of mass of a geometric object is at its centroid, and the centroid of an equilateral triangle is located $\frac{2}{3}$ of the way from a vertex to the opposite side." If anyone can help fill in the algebra or geometry that leads us to the value for $r$ I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the centres of the pennies form a triangle with sides of length $2R$. If the vertices of this triangle are A, B and C and the midpoint of side BC is O, then AOB is a right angled triangle with two sides of length $2R$ and $R$. We can use Pythagoras' theorem to find the length of its third side (AO) which is

$\sqrt{(2R)^2 - R^2} = \sqrt 3 \space R$

The line AO is an altitude of the triangle, so the centroid of the triangle is two-thirds of the way along this line, so its distance from vertex A is

$\displaystyle \frac 2 3 \sqrt3 \space R = \frac 2 {\sqrt 3} R$

Comment: Excellent explanation. Makes perfect sense. I really need to work on my geometry..